Calling internal arduino library function on Arduino IDE
I'm using Arduino IDE, I want to call internal Arduino SD.h library functions located in sd_diskio.cpp
Here is my code:
#include <sd_diskio.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define SD_MMC_CLK 7 
#define SD_MMC_CMD 9
#define SD_MMC_D0 8

#define SD_MMC_D3_CS 21


void setup() {
    
    Serial.begin(9600);
    uint8_t ssPin = SD_MMC_D3_CS;
    SPI.begin(SD_MMC_CLK, SD_MMC_D0 ,SD_MMC_CMD, SD_MMC_D3_CS);
    SPIClass spi = SPI;
    
    uint32_t frequency = 4000000;
    uint8_t pdrv = sdcard_init(ssPin, &spi, frequency);
    if (!sdSelectCard(pdrv)) {
      return 0;
    }

    if (!sdCommand(pdrv, SEND_CID, 0, NULL)) {
      char cid[16];
      bool success = sdReadBytes(pdrv, cid, 16);
      sdDeselectCard(pdrv);
      if (success) {
        Serial.println(cid);
      }
    }

}

The error i get is:

error: 'sdcard_init' was not declared in this scope

Update:
The last error not shown anymore (not sure why) there is another error:

error: 'sdSelectCard' was not declared in this scope

'sdSelectCard' is not defined by sd_diskio.h, How can I tell Arduino IDE to add sd_diskio.cpp to the compilation? (I tried Sketch->Add File... but it doens't fix the problem)

The question is about SD.h but you include a different library.  The normal SD library doesn't have any function by that name.  Where did you find this code?  I would suggest trying some more common examples.  There are several that come with the SD library.

What type of Arduino are you using?

I'm using XIAO ESP32S3 (Sense)

You just skipping the first question?

esp32 is installed on "Boards Manager" on Arduino IDE, esp32 refers to "https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32"

You need to include the SD library, and then initialise it with SD.begin(). This code is running on an ESP32 Feather, and confirms that the card reader has initialised correctly, and that a card is present.
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

#ifdef ESP32
    #define SD_CS    14     //SD card chip select
#else ifdef ESP8266
    #define SD_CS    2
#endif

void initSDcard() {
    if (!SD.begin(SD_CS)) {
        Serial.println(F("SD Card not found"));
        Serial.println(F("Remember MISO to MISO & MOSI to MOSI"));        
        while (!SD.begin(SD_CS)) {
            delay(10);
        }
    }
    Serial.println(F("SD Card OK"));        
}

void setup() {                
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(2000); 
    Serial.println("Started");
    initSDcard();
}

void loop() {
    delay(10);
}

